# How to scroll down the toolbar automatically once another fragment get loaded using bottom navigation in android jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I am using android jetpack navigation and i have bottom navigation view in my activity. I have used the toolbar scroll property. So, once i scroll the recyclerview of my fragment the toolbar scrolls up which is good. After that when i click on any item of bottom navigation another fragment get loaded. In this newly loaded fragment the toolbar is automatically scrolled up if it was scrolled up in the last loaded fragment. So, is there any way that if new fragment get loaded the toolbar automatically scroll down to its own position.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".NavMainActivity">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/color_bottom_nav_selecter"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/color_bottom_nav_selecter"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"/>
```

[image: last fragment was scrolled up, so toolbar was scrolled up, new fragment in image is automatically get loaded with scrolled up toolbar]

[image: New Fragment should be loaded like this with toolbar on its own position again]